# Apply a Tax rate to a Stripe Payment Intent

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Is it possible to add tax rate automatically for each payment intent?

I have fixed tax which is 19% and it is under some id, like: `txr_9uuad8a9sud89`...

I create the Payment Intent like this:

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'payment_method' => $paymentMethods["data"][0]["id"],
            'amount' => 11111,
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'customer' => $user->stripe_id,
            'confirmation_method' => 'automatic',
            'confirm' => true,
        ]);
```

But cannot find a way how to automatically apply tax for this payment.

Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tax rates can only be applied to [Invoices or Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/taxes/tax-rates#creating-tax-rates). To include tax on individual payments you'd have to calculate it yourself and add it to the amount of the PaymentIntent.

Comment: It's crazy to me that this isn't a feature of PaymentIntent. Do people that use PaymentIntent - as-in the multiparty payments guide - not ever pay taxes if a sale occurs in an area they have nexus?

Answer (score 3):

From the Stripe Tax FAQ: What integrations do you support for Stripe Tax?
We can support platforms integrated with Invoicing, Billing, Payment Links and Checkout integrations. **To use Stripe Tax in custom payment flows, join the Orders API beta.**

You will need to migrate from payment intents to orders.

[Orders Overview](https://stripe.com/docs/orders)

*The Orders API allows you to create custom checkout flows and use Stripe Tax to calculate taxes automatically. You can also apply discounts and coupons.*

*The Orders API is an alternative integration that generates PaymentIntents objects for each payment. If you have an existing PaymentIntents integration, you must migrate your integration to the Orders API to access this functionality, but you can continue to read the PaymentIntents objects to access details about the payment status.*

Comment: *The Orders v2 API is shutting down on October 2nd, 2023* - [source](https://stripe.com/docs/orders)

Answer (score 0):

In response `charge_response[:charges][:data][0][:balance_transaction]` is there.

So we retrieve balance transaction id and call
`response = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.retrieve(charge_response[:charges][:data][0][:balance_transaction],)`.

After that we get deduction in `response[:fee]` and settle amount after deduction in `response[:net]`